# How to add one project masterpage into another project?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Hi i am unable to add master page of one project to another project. i try to add master page from pick file window but it doesn't show another project files.

below is the structure of my Solution File

```html
-SampleWebsite             
  -WebApplication1         ------> Project 1
    -MasterPage.Master     ------> Master Page
    -web.config
  -WebApplication2         ------> Project 2
    -Default.aspx          ------> Web From
    -web.config
```

I need to apply MasterPage.Master to Default.aspx

Please suggest me on this issue......

Thanks.

Comment: If you add page to project,only that project related Master pages will be dispalyed in pick file window

Answer (score 0):

**just copy your project source and paste another place after that you open project and edit the name**